# How to download a pdf file using Ajax without href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf-generation

I have a button in HTML.

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="invoicePrint" disabled="disabled">
    <i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print Invoice
</button>
```

On click of button, ajax is called

Ajax End Code looks like this:

```
$('#invoicePrint').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    documentCommon.ajax({
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/download/invoice/' + $("#invoiceId").val() ,
            data: {
                '_CONV_ID': $('input[name="_CONV_ID"]').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {   
                
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("Server Side issues. Kindly retry or contact system administrator");
            }
        });// End ajax
});
```

When i click on button; Nothing happens, no file download
but when i chrome inspect i can see following details:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/download/invoice/6
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Invoice_99_6.pdf
Content-Length: 430385
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 06:21:50 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=A8A8ACC5AD3A925394EDB729684624FA
Host: localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/welcome
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="87", "\"Not;A\\Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Also a response binary data:
[image]

From internet i can see guys using href to download. but is it possible without using href in above code or any other alternative as browser has .pdf plugin which will be used to open this.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try "$.ajax()"？